# Turn off screen saver in MobaXterm

Tags: mobaxterm

Is there a way turn off the screen saver on MobaXterm?

MobaXterm uses a screen saver implementing penguins icons which glide across the screen during periods of user inactivity.  I would like to prevent this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must pay for that feature. It should say in the banner across the top of the window that you need the premium version to customize certain parts of the program.

Comment: Should you prefer not to use the provided binaries. you can instead download the source code from http://download.mobatek.net/sources/ and compile it yourself. Note that the MobaXterm source is released under a custom open source license that does not allow any binaries  you compile to be distributed, which is also true for any object code you create.

Comment: Does the self-compiled version include the premium features?

Comment: It's irritating how such a program with so many user hostile features and bloatware (they ship games nobody wants) became so popular on corporate Windows desktops.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to do so by editing the configuration file (`%MyDocuments%\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.ini`) directly.

Be sure to close Moba first as it overwrites the ini file upon exit.
Add the following to the Misc section:

```
[Misc]
...
TimerConst=1073741824
```

Note that with 0 and -1 the screen saver starts immediately, so I used a very large value (ca. 34 years).

The following parameters apply to the screen saver:

| Setting | Default value | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NbPenguins | 4 | Number of penguins for the "consolesaver" |
| TimerConst | 600 | Time (in seconds) before starting the "consolesaver" |
| TimerInt | 100 | Time (in ms) between each penguin move in the "consolesaver" |

See https://blog.mobatek.net/post/mobaxterm-configuration-settings/

Tested with MobaXterm Personal Edition v10.5 Build 3582.

Comment: Upvote this reply, please. It is crazy how such a useless feature increases the CPU load on my laptop when using MobaXterm 23.1. On an age where we want to be energy efficient, having a few penguins swiping the screen, raised my constant CPU usage from ~5% to over 30%. If the author(s) of this software ever read this, please disable the screensaver by default. It's not this software's job to handle that, anyway.